# firebase in_app-purchase android not showing

Tags: in-app-purchase, firebase-analytics

I would like to get help.

Android in_app_purchase event not collecting in Firebase Analytics.
IOS is being collected normally by in_app_purchase.
Also, events related to "Firebase analytic" other than "in_app_purchase" events are being collected normally.

Development Environment: unity 2020.3.26f1  c#
firebaseSDK : 8.7.0
unity IAP : 4.1.2

I checked the Firebase debug view and local log according to the instructions.
Currently, only the in_app_purchase event is not displayed in the debug view.
In the local log, "Log and bundle. event: in_app_purchase(_iap)" is displayed.

I don't know what to check anymore Has anyone had the same problem as me?

```
01-23 23:44:05.292 V/FA-SVC  (31697): Setting user property: ga_session_number(_sno), 223
01-23 23:44:05.299 V/FA-SVC  (31697): Setting user property: ga_session_id(_sid), 1642949045
01-23 23:44:05.306 V/FA-SVC  (31697): Parsed config. version, gmp_app_id: 1639597852782409, 1:327451421140:android:9c547b5ed466b580
01-23 23:44:05.306 V/FA-SVC  (31697): Logging event: origin=auto,name=session_start(_s),params=Bundle[{ga_event_origin(_o)=auto, ga_session_id(_sid)=1642949045}]
01-23 23:44:05.311 V/FA-SVC  (31697): Upload scheduled in approximately ms: 181
01-23 23:44:05.311 V/FA-SVC  (31697): Unscheduling upload
01-23 23:44:05.312 V/FA-SVC  (31697): Scheduling upload, millis: 181
01-23 23:44:05.313 V/FA-SVC  (31697): Background event processing time, ms: 7
01-23 23:44:05.324 V/FA-SVC  (31697): Saving default event parameters, appId, data size: com.android.vending, 2
01-23 23:44:05.332 D/FA-SVC  (31697): Log and bundle. event: in_app_purchase(_iap)
01-23 23:44:05.362 V/FA-SVC  (31697): Checking account type status for ad personalization signals
01-23 23:44:05.394 D/FA-SVC  (31697): Turning off ad personalization due to account type
01-23 23:44:05.395 D/FA-SVC  (31697): Marking in-app purchase as real-time
01-23 23:44:05.406 V/FA-SVC  (31697): Device PackageMeasurementTaskService is starting up
01-23 23:44:05.410 V/FA-SVC  (31697): Device ChimeraPackageMeasurementTaskService called.
01-23 23:44:05.418 D/FA-SVC  (31697): Log and bundle processed. event, size, time_ms: in_app_purchase(_iap), 981, 86
01-23 23:44:05.421 V/FA-SVC  (31697): Updated engagement user property. scope, value: lifetime, 114588
01-23 23:44:05.422 V/FA-SVC  (31697): Updated engagement user property. scope, value: session-scoped, 114587
01-23 23:44:05.422 V/FA-SVC  (31697): Checking account type status for ad personalization signals
01-23 23:44:05.422 D/FA-SVC  (31697): Turning off ad personalization due to account type
01-23 23:44:05.426 V/FA-SVC  (31697): Saving bundle, size: 801
01-23 23:44:05.434 D/FA-SVC  (31697): Uploading events. Elapsed time since last upload attempt (ms): 927
01-23 23:44:05.436 V/FA-SVC  (31697): Uploading data. app, uncompressed size, data: com.h2kresearch.preciousHangul, 1077, 
01-23 23:44:05.436 V/FA-SVC  (31697): batch {
01-23 23:44:05.436 V/FA-SVC  (31697):   bundle {
01-23 23:44:05.436 V/FA-SVC  (31697):     protocol_version: 1
01-23 23:44:05.436 V/FA-SVC  (31697):     platform: android
01-23 23:44:05.436 V/FA-SVC  (31697):     gmp_version: 50018
01-23 23:44:05.436 V/FA-SVC  (31697):     uploading_gmp_version: 214815
01-23 23:44:05.436 V/FA-SVC  (31697):     dynamite_version: 59
01-23 23:44:05.436 V/FA-SVC  (31697):     config_version: 1638856465953841
01-23 23:44:05.436 V/FA-SVC  (31697):     gmp_app_id: 1:624596310862:android:9c231c7bec49333471dc1f
01-23 23:44:05.436 V/FA-SVC  (31697):     admob_app_id: 
01-23 23:44:05.436 V/FA-SVC  (31697):     app_id: com.h2kresearch.preciousHangul
01-23 23:44:05.436 V/FA-SVC  (31697):     app_version: 3.5.11
01-23 23:44:05.436 V/FA-SVC  (31697):     app_version_major: 211
01-23 23:44:05.436 V/FA-SVC  (31697):     firebase_instance_id: dbzQiYKYSX2o_FDuevw_RX
01-23 23:44:05.436 V/FA-SVC  (31697):     dev_cert_hash: -5595168113650675036
01-23 23:44:05.436 V/FA-SVC  (31697):     app_store: 
01-23 23:44:05.436 V/FA-SVC  (31697):     upload_timestamp_millis: 1642949045419
01-23 23:44:05.436 V/FA-SVC  (31697):     start_timestamp_millis: 1642949044412
01-23 23:44:05.436 V/FA-SVC  (31697):     end_timestamp_millis: 1642949044796
01-23 23:44:05.436 V/FA-SVC  (31697):     previous_bundle_start_timestamp_millis: 1642949045034
01-23 23:44:05.436 V/FA-SVC  (31697):     previous_bundle_end_timestamp_millis: 1642949045034
01-23 23:44:05.436 V/FA-SVC  (31697):     app_instance_id: 52e4fa24fa2d6bce2c51e7cade90e8ae
01-23 23:44:05.436 V/FA-SVC  (31697):     resettable_device_id: 8043f731-eaac-443a-a7bc-7800b876f154
01-23 23:44:05.436 V/FA-SVC  (31697):     ds_id: DSID=AAO-7r4-u_Tnoim76yP6SeI1QxN9XIxj-OuaHytzVEdvquoj3tsavH5xYeCuHu6AaGXZBzfnru5ZQI-Jhg5ZSNKq_dQLJ01pv5DD5Jg0eMlR2mQspYNkbxo
01-23 23:44:05.436 V/FA-SVC  (31697):     limited_ad_tracking: true
01-23 23:44:05.436 V/FA-SVC  (31697):     os_version: 11
01-23 23:44:05.436 V/FA-SVC  (31697):     device_model: LM-V500N
01-23 23:44:05.436 V/FA-SVC  (31697):     user_default_language: ko-kr
01-23 23:44:05.436 V/FA-SVC  (31697):     time_zone_offset_minutes: 540
01-23 23:44:05.436 V/FA-SVC  (31697):     bundle_sequential_index: 7
01-23 23:44:05.436 V/FA-SVC  (31697):     service_upload: true
01-23 23:44:05.436 V/FA-SVC  (31697):     health_monitor: 
01-23 23:44:05.436 V/FA-SVC  (31697):     consent_signals: G1--
01-23 23:44:05.436 V/FA-SVC  (31697):     user_property {
01-23 23:44:05.436 V/FA-SVC  (31697):       set_timestamp_millis: 1642948926782
01-23 23:44:05.436 V/FA-SVC  (31697):       name: first_open_time(_fot)
01-23 23:44:05.436 V/FA-SVC  (31697):       string_value: 
01-23 23:44:05.436 V/FA-SVC  (31697):       int_value: 1642950000000
01-23 23:44:05.436 V/FA-SVC  (31697):     }
01-23 23:44:05.436 V/FA-SVC  (31697):     user_property {
01-23 23:44:05.436 V/FA-SVC  (31697):       set_timestamp_millis: 1642948926782
01-23 23:44:05.436 V/FA-SVC  (31697):       name: first_open_after_install(_fi)
01-23 23:44:05.436 V/FA-SVC  (31697):       string_value: 
01-23 23:44:05.436 V/FA-SVC  (31697):       int_value: 1
01-23 23:44:05.436 V/FA-SVC  (31697):     }
01-23 23:44:05.436 V/FA-SVC  (31697):     user_property {
01-23 23:44:05.436 V/FA-SVC  (31697):       set_timestamp_millis: 1642948927077
01-23 23:44:05.436 V/FA-SVC  (31697):       name: ga_session_number(_sno)
01-23 23:44:05.436 V/FA-SVC  (31697):       string_value: 
01-23 23:44:05.436 V/FA-SVC  (31697):       int_value: 1
01-23 23:44:05.436 V/FA-SVC  (31697):     }
01-23 23:44:05.436 V/FA-SVC  (31697):     user_property {
01-23 23:44:05.436 V/FA-SVC  (31697):       set_timestamp_millis: 1642948927077
01-23 23:44:05.436 V/FA-SVC  (31697):       name: ga_session_id(_sid)
01-23 23:44:05.436 V/FA-SVC  (31697):       string_value: 
01-23 23:44:05.436 V/FA-SVC  (31697):       int_value: 1642948927
01-23 23:44:05.436 V/FA-SVC  (31697):     }
01-23 23:44:05.436 V/FA-SVC  (31697):     user_property {
01-23 23:44:05.436 V/FA-SVC  (31697):       set_timestamp_millis: 1642949045420
01-23 23:44:05.436 V/FA-SVC  (31697):       name: lifetime_user_engagement(_lte)
01-23 23:44:05.436 V/FA-SVC  (31697):       string_value: 
01-23 23:44:05.436 V/FA-SVC  (31697):       int_value: 114588
01-23 23:44:05.436 V/FA-SVC  (31697):     }
01-23 23:44:05.436 V/FA-SVC  (31697):     user_property {
01-23 23:44:05.436 V/FA-SVC  (31697):       set_timestamp_millis: 1642949045421
01-23 23:44:05.436 V/FA-SVC  (31697):       name: session_user_engagement(_se)
01-23 23:44:05.436 V/FA-SVC  (31697):       string_value: 
01-23 23:44:05.436 V/FA-SVC  (31697):       int_value: 114587
01-23 23:44:05.436 V/FA-SVC  (31697):     }
01-23 23:44:05.436 V/FA-SVC  (31697):     user_property {
01-23 23:44:05.436 V/FA-SVC  (31697):       set_timestamp_millis: 1642948967219
01-23 23:44:05.436 V/FA-SVC  (31697):       name: birthday
01-23 23:44:05.436 V/FA-SVC  (31697):       string_value: 2014/5
01-23 23:44:05.436 V/FA-SVC  (31697):     }
01-23 23:44:05.436 V/FA-SVC  (31697):     user_property {
01-23 23:44:05.436 V/FA-SVC  (31697):       set_timestamp_millis: 1642948967219
01-23 23:44:05.436 V/FA-SVC  (31697):       name: childLevel
01-23 23:44:05.436 V/FA-SVC  (31697):       string_value: ì‹¤ë ¥
01-23 23:44:05.436 V/FA-SVC  (31697):     }
01-23 23:44:05.436 V/FA-SVC  (31697):     user_property {
01-23 23:44:05.436 V/FA-SVC  (31697):       set_timestamp_millis: 1642949045362
01-23 23:44:05.436 V/FA-SVC  (31697):       name: non_personalized_ads(_npa)
01-23 23:44:05.436 V/FA-SVC  (31697):       string_value: 
01-23 23:44:05.436 V/FA-SVC  (31697):       int_value: 1
01-23 23:44:05.436 V/FA-SVC  (31697):     }
01-23 23:44:05.436 V/FA-SVC  (31697):     event {
01-23 23:44:05.436 V/FA-SVC  (31697):       name: button_purchase_1_month_subscription
01-23 23:44:05.436 V/FA-SVC  (31697):       timestamp_millis: 1642949044412
01-23 23:44:05.436 V/FA-SVC  (31697):       previous_timestamp_millis: 0
01-23 23:44:05.436 V/FA-SVC  (31697):       param {
01-23 23:44:05.436 V/FA-SVC  (31697):         name: ga_event_origin(_o)
01-23 23:44:05.436 V/FA-SVC  (31697):         string_value: app
01-23 23:44:05.436 V/FA-SVC  (31697):       }
01-23 23:44:05.436 V/FA-SVC  (31697):       param {
01-23 23:44:05.436 V/FA-SVC  (31697):         name: _r
01-23 23:44:05.436 V/FA-SVC  (31697):         int_value: 1
01-23 23:44:05.436 V/FA-SVC  (31697):       }
01-23 23:44:05.436 V/FA-SVC  (31697):       param {
01-23 23:44:05.436 V/FA-SVC  (31697):         name: ga_screen_class(_sc)
01-23 23:44:05.436 V/FA-SVC  (31697):         string_value: MessagingUnityPlayerActivity
01-23 23:44:05.436 V/FA-SVC  (31697):       }
01-23 23:44:05.436 V/FA-SVC  (31697):       param {
01-23 23:44:05.436 V/FA-SVC  (31697):         name: ga_screen_id(_si)
01-23 23:44:05.436 V/FA-SVC  (31697):         int_value: -4806888754585693379
01-23 23:44:05.436 V/FA-SVC  (31697):       }
01-23 23:44:05.436 V/FA-SVC  (31697):       param {
01-23 23:44:05.436 V/FA-SVC  (31697):         name: _dbg
01-23 23:44:05.436 V/FA-SVC  (31697):         int_value: 1
01-23 23:44:05.436 V/FA-SVC  (31697):       }
01-23 23:44:05.436 V/FA-SVC  (31697):     }
01-23 23:44:05.436 V/FA-SVC  (31697):     event {
01-23 23:44:05.436 V/FA-SVC  (31697):       name: button_purchase
01-23 23:44:05.436 V/FA-SVC  (31697):       timestamp_millis: 1642949044423
01-23 23:44:05.436 V/FA-SVC  (31697):       previous_timestamp_millis: 0
01-23 23:44:05.436 V/FA-SVC  (31697):       param {
01-23 23:44:05.436 V/FA-SVC  (31697):         name: ga_event_origin(_o)
01-23 23:44:05.436 V/FA-SVC  (31697):         string_value: app
01-23 23:44:05.436 V/FA-SVC  (31697):       }
01-23 23:44:05.436 V/FA-SVC  (31697):       param {
01-23 23:44:05.436 V/FA-SVC  (31697):         name: _r
01-23 23:44:05.436 V/FA-SVC  (31697):         int_value: 1
01-23 23:44:05.436 V/FA-SVC  (31697):       }
01-23 23:44:05.436 V/FA-SVC  (31697):       param {
01-23 23:44:05.436 V/FA-SVC  (31697):         name: ga_screen_class(_sc)
01-23 23:44:05.436 V/FA-SVC  (31697):         string_value: MessagingUnityPlayerActivity
01-23 23:44:05.436 V/FA-SVC  (31697):       }
01-23 23:44:05.436 V/FA-SVC  (31697):       param {
01-23 23:44:05.436 V/FA-SVC  (31697):         name: ga_screen_id(_si)
01-23 23:44:05.436 V/FA-SVC  (31697):         int_value: -4806888754585693379
01-23 23:44:05.436 V/FA-SVC  (31697):       }
01-23 23:44:05.436 V/FA-SVC  (31697):       param {
01-23 23:44:05.436 V/FA-SVC  (31697):         name: _dbg
01-23 23:44:05.436 V/FA-SVC  (31697):         int_value: 1
01-23 23:44:05.436 V/FA-SVC  (31697):       }
01-23 23:44:05.436 V/FA-SVC  (31697):       param {
01-23 23:44:05.436 V/FA-SVC  (31697):         name: product_id
01-23 23:44:05.436 V/FA-SVC  (31697):         string_value: 1_month_subscription
01-23 23:44:05.436 V/FA-SVC  (31697):       }
01-23 23:44:05.436 V/FA-SVC  (31697):     }
01-23 23:44:05.436 V/FA-SVC  (31697):     event {
01-23 23:44:05.436 V/FA-SVC  (31697):       name: screen_view(_vs)
01-23 23:44:05.436 V/FA-SVC  (31697):       timestamp_millis: 1642949044796
01-23 23:44:05.436 V/FA-SVC  (31697):       previous_timestamp_millis: 1642948965316
01-23 23:44:05.436 V/FA-SVC  (31697):       param {
01-23 23:44:05.436 V/FA-SVC  (31697):         name: ga_event_origin(_o)
01-23 23:44:05.436 V/FA-SVC  (31697):         string_value: auto
01-23 23:44:05.436 V/FA-SVC  (31697):       }
01-23 23:44:05.436 V/FA-SVC  (31697):       param {
01-23 23:44:05.436 V/FA-SVC  (31697):         name: _r
01-23 23:44:05.436 V/FA-SVC  (31697):         int_value: 1
01-23 23:44:05.436 V/FA-SVC  (31697):       }
01-23 23:44:05.436 V/FA-SVC  (31697):       param {
01-23 23:44:05.436 V/FA-SVC  (31697):         name: ga_previous_class(_pc)
01-23 23:44:05.436 V/FA-SVC  (31697):         string_value: MessagingUnityPlayerActivity
01-23 23:44:05.436 V/FA-SVC  (31697):       }
01-23 23:44:05.436 V/FA-SVC  (31697):       param {
01-23 23:44:05.436 V/FA-SVC  (31697):         name: ga_previous_id(_pi)
01-23 23:44:05.436 V/FA-SVC  (31697):         int_value: -4806888754585693379
01-23 23:44:05.436 V/FA-SVC  (31697):       }
01-23 23:44:05.436 V/FA-SVC  (31697):       param {
01-23 23:44:05.436 V/FA-SVC  (31697):         name: ga_screen_class(_sc)
01-23 23:44:05.436 V/FA-SVC  (31697):         string_value: ProxyBillingActivity
01-23 23:44:05.436 V/FA-SVC  (31697):       }
01-23 23:44:05.436 V/FA-SVC  (31697):       param {
01-23 23:44:05.436 V/FA-SVC  (31697):         name: ga_screen_id(_si)
01-23 23:44:05.436 V/FA-SVC  (31697):         int_value: 2499972332425371912
01-23 23:44:05.436 V/FA-SVC  (31697):       }
01-23 23:44:05.436 V/FA-SVC  (31697):       param {
01-23 23:44:05.436 V/FA-SVC  (31697):         name: _dbg
01-23 23:44:05.436 V/FA-SVC  (31697):         int_value: 1
01-23 23:44:05.436 V/FA-SVC  (31697):       }
01-23 23:44:05.436 V/FA-SVC  (31697):       param {
01-23 23:44:05.436 V/FA-SVC  (31697):         name: engagement_time_msec(_et)
01-23 23:44:05.436 V/FA-SVC  (31697):         int_value: 79375
01-23 23:44:05.436 V/FA-SVC  (31697):       }
01-23 23:44:05.436 V/FA-SVC  (31697):     }
01-23 23:44:05.436 V/FA-SVC  (31697):   }
01-23 23:44:05.436 V/FA-SVC  (31697): }
```

Comment: I got the same issue. Does anyone know the solution? Thanks!

Comment: did you link the Firebase app to developer account in Google Play console? See https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/6392038